# Why does it says undefined in menu on mobile?

Tags: html

I don't really understand what happened here.

Site on pc: auxproducts.comuv.com/david/

You can see everything looks normal there.

But whenever you put it on mobile it messes up?

http://mobt.me/C660

Check there.

And why does the menu say undefined?

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Keep the language clean...

Comment: Can we just have a link to your site? not to some emulator

Answer (score 1):

Primarily this issue comes with any of JS conflict or base path definition in settings. If everything is fine, then you need to do hack like this. Jump into code and you will find the culprit. In my case - I have removed and add

structure to re-form the menu.
It works !

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your Angular code you must have

```
<span class="title">{{ variable_name }}</span>
```

And the issue is there on desktop also, but that section of the page is displayed differently on wider screens so you don't realise.

If you view the source of your page on any device you will see:

```
<div id="titleBar"><a href="#navPanel" class="toggle"></a><span class="title">undefined</span></div>
```

So try to find where that is in your code and make sure the variable is defined.

This isn't a mobile issue its an issue with your code, so don't focus on the mobile aspects of it just because the problem is only visible on mobile.

Comment: It's no where in my code. I don't use angular for that part, only for the table.